# GHC chooses different instances for the same expression?

Tags: haskell, ghc, typeclass

I want to implement an arrow with an `arr`-member-function showing a different behavior for function arguments with different types, for instance `arr (\x -> (x,x))` should behave differently from `arr id`...

Here's the code:

```
{-# LANGUAGE Arrows, OverlappingInstances, IncoherentInstances, FlexibleInstances#-}
import Control.Arrow
import Control.Category 
import Prelude hiding (id, (.))

class ToPredefinedStr a where
  toStr :: a -> String


instance ToPredefinedStr ((->) b (b,b)) where
  toStr _ = "b -> (b,b)"

instance ToPredefinedStr (a -> (b,c)) where
  toStr _ = "a -> (b,c)" 

instance ToPredefinedStr ((a,b) -> c) where
  toStr _ = "(a,b) -> c"

instance ToPredefinedStr (a -> b) where 
  toStr _ = "a -> b"

newtype MyArrow a b c = MA (a b (c, String))

instance (Category a, Arrow a) => Category (MyArrow a) where
    -- irrelevant for this example ...

instance (Arrow a) => Arrow (MyArrow a) where
    arr f        = MA (arr (\x -> (f x, toStr f)))

appMyArr (MA a) = a
```

But: It shows the following very strange behavor:

```
> toStr (\x -> (x,x)) -- that works as expected!
"b -> (b,b)" 
> appMyArr (arr (\x -> (x,x))) () -- but this does'nt!!
(((),()),"a -> b")
```

Can anyone explain how to get ghci to choose the `b -> (b,b)`-instance for the expression `\x -> (x,x)` in the second example?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The short answer is that this happens because the compiler has access to more specific type information in the first case than in the second.

When compiling your definition of `arr`, the compiler only sees the type of the function argument `f` as `b -> c`, so when considering the call `toStr f` it has to choose an instance based on only this information. After all, `arr` might be called with any function. It is clear that it can only choose the `instance ToPredefinedStr (a -> b)`.

Now, when we inline it like in `toStr (\b -> (b, b))`, the compiler has more information available at the call site, and can choose the more specific instance.

And no, using `INLINE` pragmas won't change the instance selection if you were thinking of that.

For what you're trying to achieve, the closest I can think of would be to restrict the types so that the instance selection will happen *outside* `arr`:

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts, ... #-}

class FancyArrow a where
    myArr :: (ToPredefinedStr (b -> c)) => (b -> c) -> a b c 
    ...

instance (Arrow a) => FancyArrow (MyArrow a) where
    myArr f        = MA (arr (\x -> (f x, toStr f)))
```

This gives the result you wanted.

```
*Main> appMyArr (myArr (\x -> (x,x))) ()
(((),()),"b -> (b,b)")
```

Note that this is somewhat brittle, as you have to control where the choice of instance is made by propagating the `ToPredefinedStr` constraint. For example, this function silently changes behavior if you remove the type signature.

```
foo :: (Arrow a, ToPredefinedStr (b -> c)) => (b -> c) -> a b (c, String)
foo f = appMyArr (myArr f)
```

Comment: An interesting suggestion; I'll definitely give this a try tomorrow! ... Why do you think it could'nt work?

Comment: Mostly because it won't work with the standard `Arrow` class, but if you're fine with that then sure, it should work. However, it feels somewhat brittle.

Answer (score 10):

If you use `IncoherentInstances` anything can happen. There is no longer any promise the instances are picked in a coherent way.

Comment: I thought, IncoherentInstances would go from top to bottom, picking the first instance that fits...?

Comment: @phynfo: The first instance that fits given the inferred types for the context from which it goes looking. I'm unclear on the details and the GHC User Guide is somewhat taciturn on the subject, but hammar's answer sounds plausible. But really, it's *incoherent*. It says it *right there in the name*. What did you expect? :]